# Problemas con un component creado con vuejs

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js

Tengo el siguiente código, que me retorna una lista, la cual se carga en una tabla.

```
Vue.component('tickets',{

  template: '#tickets-template',

  data: function(){
    return{
      tickets:[]
    }
  },
  created:function(){
    this.getTickets();
  },
  methods: {

    getTickets: function(){

      $.getJSON('/findalltickets', function(tickets) {
          /*optional stuff to do after success */
          this.tickets = tickets;
      }.bind(this));

      setTimeout(this.getTickets, 10000);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

El detalle está que cuando agrego a mi base de datos un nuevo registro automáticamente sin <kbd>F5</kbd>, me reconoce el nuevo registro en la tabla de mi `div` pero los eventos *click* que tengo ligados con *jQuery* sobre esa tabla ya no funcionan sobre ese último registro ingresado, pero sí en los anteriores.

Comment: ¿Qué eventos? ¿Puedes mostrarlos?, por otro lado, existe alguna razón por la que tengas el `setTimeout`?

Comment: Esto generalmente es porque el nuevo registro se crea una vez se han asociado los eventos, y se soluciona usando eventos delegados... pero necesitaríamos ver el modo en que asocias los eventos para saber si ese es el motivo

Comment: Lo ideal no es cargar todos los registros cada vez que ingreses un registro nuevo, yo intentaria que el server solo me respondiera con el elemento registrado y hacer un push a la lista de elementos, puedes intentar de esta forma